# Ns_error_domain attribute only valid on enum/struct/union/class error building Realm 2.0.0 + Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, realm, xcode8

I'm trying to build an Objective-C project in Xcode8 with Realm 2.0.0 (installed via CocoaPods) and I'm getting a Semantic Issue error:

> Ns_error_domain attribute only valid on enum/struct/union/class

The error comes from `RLMConstants.h:100`

`typedef RLM_ERROR_ENUM(NSInteger, RLMError, RLMErrorDomain) {`

I'm building against iOS SDK 10. I've also tested the latest Realm 1.x with the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that [some Realm headers were unintentionally incompatible with Objective-C++ when using the C++98 language dialect](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4164). This has been [fixed on Realm's master branch](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4168) and should make it into a release in the near future.